# Is it possible to load a subset of columns using Sybase 15 bcp?

Tags: sap-ase, bcp

I have a CSV file with 20 or so columns and I want to load it into a table with only 9 columns - I want to throw away the rest.

Can I do it directly with bcp or do I need to preprocess the file to strip it down to just what I need?

The [manual](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.docset.ase_15.0/title.htm) does not seem to detail it.

But then I seem to have options that arent in the manual, eg -labeled ?

Thanks in advance, Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible with bcp.

Comment: Thanks - was thinking with the format file options it might have been possible...

Answer (score 1):

You can combine pipes, awk and bcp.
F.e.

In the first shell:

mknod bcp.pipe p

cat  > awk  > bcp.pipe

in the second shell:

bcp db..table in bcp.pipe -c -U ...

Comment: Thanks - thats what I've started working on - now having the fun of parsing CSV with awk :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a view on the table which only includes the columns you want. Then bcp out the view instead of the table.